# unable to return html element in xsl script

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using IE 9 browser and below is my xml and xsl

When i open in browser it shows me error saying
"Keyword msxsl:script may not contain h:td."
Please suggest .

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="doc.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<books>
<book>
<name>book1</name>
<qty>2</qty>
</book>
<book>
<name>book2</name>
<qty>2</qty>
</book>
<book>
<name>book3</name>
<qty>2</qty>
</book>
</books>
```

### xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:user="com.nitish"
xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user" >
function row(){

    return (<h:td>hello</h:td>);
}

</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="/">

 <html>
<body>
<h2>Book Details</h2>
<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/" border="1">
<xsl:for-each select="//book">
<h:tr><h:td><xsl:value-of select="name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="user:row()"/></h:td></h:tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</h:table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i open in browser it shows me error saying
"Keyword msxsl:script may not contain h:td."
Please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

If you need a callable component to return a node then you can simply write a template and call it e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="row">
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

then you can call `<xsl:call-template name="row"/>`. That is pure XSLT 1.0 and does not depend on proprietary extensions to use Javascript.

If you really want to construct nodes with JScript for MSXML in IE then I think you need

```
<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user" ><![CDATA[
function row(){
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0');
    doc.loadXML('<tr><td>hello</td></tr>');
    return doc.documentElement;
}

]]></msxsl:script>
```

and then use e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="user:row()"/>` in XSLT. Untested, and might need `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0` in later versions of IE. And in my view nothing is gained that way compared to simply constructing nodes with XSLT templates.